# Root of the $\zeta(s) = s$

Tags: riemann-zeta

What is the root $s_0$ of the equation $\zeta(s) = s$, where  $\zeta(s)$ is Euler zeta function? This point $s_0$ has obvious property: the segment $(1,s_0]$ to the left of it is mapping on the  half-line $[s_0,  \infty )$ to the right. Is it expressed through Euler–Mascheroni constant $\gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not *known* to possess a closed form expression. Their numerical values are

> $x_+=\quad1.833772651680271396245648589441523592180\ldots
> \\x_-=-~0.2959050055752139556472378310830480\ldots$

See [OEIS A$69995$](http://oeis.org/A069995) and [OEIS A$69857$](http://oeis.org/A069857).